# Creating a responsive flex box with same size images

Tags: html, css, flexbox

New to html/CSS, learning flex boxes, I feel I've followed the W3schools website [example](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_flex-wrap_wrap) correctly and I also took some code from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp) on making it responsive, but I can't get the images to wrap when the viewport is reduced.

Here is my code to start:
CSS:

```
* {font-family: arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box;}

html body {margin: 0;}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 .5%;
}

.flex-container > div {
    margin: 1%;
}

.whatwecando {padding-top: 125px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.nav {position:flex; top:0; left:0;
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 20px; 
    float: left; 
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 25px;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    flex-direction: row;
    /* vertical alignement */
    align-items: center;
    /* how you want horizontal distribution */
    /* space-evenly | space-around | space-between */
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.item {
    color: white;
}

.item:first-child {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:500px){
    .column {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

ul {list-style: none}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="flex-container">

<div><img src="Images/Printing/Banner.jpg" style="max-width:100%; height: auto;" width="100%" alt="Banners" /></div>
<div><img src="Images/Printing/Banner.jpg" style="max-width:100%; height: auto;" width="100%" alt="Posters" /></div>
<div><img src="Images/Printing/Banner.jpg" style="max-width:100%; height: auto;" width="100%" alt="Flock again" /></div>
```

When I add the `flex-wrap: wrap;` (which would logically be the solution) in the container class, all the images become lined up vertically, so I had removed it.
I'm tryingn to create like a grid of images, am I not understanding flexboxes correctly?

Comment: would be because of the *original size* of your images - I can't see any issue actually... **When I add the flex-wrap: wrap; (which would logically be the solution) in the container class, all the images become lined up vertically** => increase the width of the browser window, you can see proper wrapping

Comment: You were right about the sizing. I added flex-wrap: wrap; and reduced the % width of the images, but they're still aligned vertically. Do I have to create a new container for each column? I'm so confused

Comment: check this out and try changing the width: https://jsfiddle.net/zg4vd3st/ See how they wrap below one by one when width increases

Comment: That is so strange....it works. I tried copying my code into it and it works properly. Is dreamweaver not a good IDE to use? When I run the code on chrome through dreamweaver, it shows them all vertically aligned even on a 1080p display view port :S

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple and nice [guide to flexbox content](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). I think you got something mixed (classes in css and html).

Here's another thing to try to make images have the same size:

```
.image-container{
    width:100px;
}
.image-container img {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    object-fit:cover;
}
```

(image height must be fixed for this to work).

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. I have suggested an edit to your post to improve the formatting of your code sample. Can I also suggest you summarise the key information from the link in your answer, to help the question asker and other visitors understand it (especially useful in case the link breaks). There is a guide to how to answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer